# How to access the owner email of win in salesforce iOS

Tags: ios, email, salesforce

Let's say I have an App named SalesSample. which uses salesforce, one of my teammates wins a deal in salesforce but doesn't use the SalesSample app. From the SalesSample app, can I email winner of deal even though they don't use SalesSample? Does salesforce api give us access to email of person who won deal?
If possible, can someone give me the steps on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found a solution. I just query the Opportunity for the record, check the user who owns it.

```
NSString *theRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Owner.Email FROM Opportunity "];
SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:theRequest];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
```

then used the email using MessageUI.framework:

```
- (void)showEmail:(id)sender {
NSString  *emailTitle = @"Email Subject";
NSString  *messageBody = @"Email Content";
NSArray  *toRecipents = [NSArray  arrayWithObject:@"Returned Email from query here"];

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError  *)error
{
if(error) {
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mail Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [errorView show];
} else {
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
// Close the Mail Interface
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```